# Embedded HubSpot form as a React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, hubspot

I'm trying to do what the title suggests. That is, I want the following vanilla JS code from HubSpot to work as a React component for my website:

```
<script charset="utf-8" type="text/javascript" src="//js.hsforms.net/forms/embed/v2.js">    </script>
<script>
  hbspt.forms.create({
    region: "na1",
    portalId: "key",
    formId: "key"
  });
</script>
```

However, I'm having a tough time doing this conversion. What would be a simple approach to solve this?